# How to make a one to many relation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database, rails-activerecord

here is what i want to have:

```
-table Announce (id, title, description,..) 

-table city (id, name) 

-table Annouce_city (idAnnouce, idCity)
```

Once an annouce is created, a line is automatically added to the Annouce_city table containing the Announce id and the id city selected

So for now i succeeded in creating a one_to_many relation but it's not what i want, since the Annouce_city table should have an announce one time but a city many times.

thanks!

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25 }
validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class Annonce < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :marque, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 35 }
validates :couleur, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2, maximum: 35 }
validates :user_id, presence: true
mount_uploaders :imgs, ImgUploader
serialize :imgs, JSON
end

class AnnonceCity < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :annonce
belongs_to :city
end
```

Comment: That is because you didn't create one-to-many relationship but many-to-many. Can you include your models in the question?

Comment: Think he's asking how to make "many to many"

Comment: Remis07 can you include your models please?

Answer (score 1):

[`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
#app/models/announcement.rb
class Announcement < ActiveRecord::Base
   #id | title | description | etc
   has_many :announcement_cities
   has_many :cities, through: :announcement_cities
end

#app/models/announcement_city.rb
class AnnouncementCity < ActiveRecord::Base
   #id | annoucement_id | city_id
   belongs_to :announcement
   belongs_to :city
end

#app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   #id | name | etc
   has_many :announcement_cities
   has_many :cities, through: :announcement_cities  
end
```

The above will give you the ability to create an `announcement` for any number of `cities` (which is basically what you have already):

```
#app/controllers/announcements_controller.rb
class AnnouncementsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @city         = City.find params[:city_id]
      @announcement = @city.announcements.new announcement_params
      @announcement.save
   end
end
```

--

If you wanted to create *one* announcement, and have that replicated for *every* city, you'll need to make a custom method:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :announcements do
   post :all_cities, on: :collection #-> url.com/announcements/all_cities
end

#app/controllers/announcements_controller.rb
class AnnouncementsController < ApplicationController
   def all_cities
      @announcement = Announcement.new announcement_params
      if @announcement.save
         @cities = City.all
         @cities.each do |city|
            city.announcements << announcement
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks RIch, but the problem here is that an Announce could have many annoucement_cities: (has_many :announcement_cities) and i actually want the city to have only one annoucement_cities..

Comment: N'est pas possible. `annoucement_city` is the join table, which means that it stores the "link" between `announcement` and `city`. If you wanted *one* announcement and lots of cities, you'll need a table like it, or `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You *could* use a uniq validation / index to make sure that each announcement is only submitted once per city